# how can in create a model for each user in Django?

Tags: django

i am trying to create a model for each user. and I want, the user o be able to upload a file to them model.

for example the user be able to upload a file to them model fro this template:

```
{% block content %}
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input  type="file" id="files" name="files" multiple="multiple" />
     <p class="container" style="margin-top: 10px">
         <input type="submit" value="upload" class="btn btn-primary" />
     </p>
</form>
{% endblock%}
```

i need a sample code for form.py, model.py, views.py,

Answer (score 0):

**models.py**

```
class Job(models.Model):
    company               = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    position              = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    file                  = models.FileField(upload_to='file/')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.position)
```

**forms.py**

```
class JobPostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Job
        #fields = "__all__"  (if you want all model field if not see below how to take each one)
        fields = [
            "company",
            "position",
            "file"
        ]
```

**views.py**

```
def job_post(request):      
    form = JobPostForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())
    context = {
        "form": form,
    }
    return render(request, "job/job_post.html", context)
```

**job/job_post.html**

```
   <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %} 
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Post</button>             
   </form>
```

another way in **job/job_post.html**

```html
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %} 
    <!--name should same as model field name-->
    <input  type="text" name="company"  />  
    <input  type="text" name="position" />
    <input  type="file" name="file" multiple="multiple" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Post</button>             
</form>
```